# Insert image after first 3 posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4

I have a 15 posts being shown in array list `<% @posts.each do |post| %>`. I'd like to insert my ads image after the first 3 posts only. NOT every 3 posts. How can I achieve that?

been looking at this http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html but don't know which one is suitable for my question.

Comment: try this `@posts.insert(3, "add here")`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<% @posts.each_with_index do |post,i|%>
 <%if i == 2 %>
  #your image here
 <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using each with index

```
<%@posts.each.with_index(1) do |post, index| %>
<% if index==3 %>
   your code to insert image
<%end%>
```

Comment: not working, still give me every 3posts not first 3 posts

Comment: have you sorted @posts

Answer (score 0):

After the third post it will place an add

```
`<% @posts.each_with_index do |post,index| %>
      <% if index == 3 %>
         <%= place_add_here %>
      <% end %>
 <% end %>`
```

Comment: Are you using any sort of caching? 
If yes please clear the cache and also clear the browser cache and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<% ADD_AFTER = [3,7,8,15]%>
<% @posts.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
   <%if ADDS_AFTER.include?(index)%>
    #MY FAV ADD CONTENT
   <%end%>
    #Regular code
<%end%>
```

Give Line Number in ADD_AFTER and it will print your advertisement after the desired line nujmber

Answer (score 0):

Since the other methods listed are not working. This is one way to achieve it.

```
<% counter = 0 %>
<% @posts.each do |post|%>
   <%if counter == 2 %>
   #your image here
  <%end%>
  <% counter++ %>
<%end%>
```